# Delete all files from remote repository committed in past 5 days

Tags: git, powershell

I have a batch file with the following commands that will cause all files in my remote repository to be removed:

```
git rm -r  *
git commit -m "All Files Deleted"
git push
```

Instead of removing all files, is there any way to remove only files committed in the past 5 days?

Comment: this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to remove all files from my git repository that have been committed within the past 5 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get a list of them and then remove them:

```
git diff --name-only $( git log --since=5.days.ago --pretty=%h --quiet | tail -n 1 ) | xargs git rm
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm working in Windows.  Is tail specific to Linux? When running in Powershell I get a message that says 'tail' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: It's a standard *NIX filter. Try with git bash.

Comment: Just had a lapsus there :-O